# Choosing from multiple columns by column name stored in a column

Tags: mysql

I want to select from a table like this

```
|id|col_name|col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|...|col100|
| 1|col1    | 142| 241| 333| 417| 713|...|   125|
| 2|col5    | 927|  72| 403| 104| 136|...|   739|
| 3|col100  | 358| 842| 150| 125| 174|...|   103|
```

Select from column specified by col_name field. Something like

```
SELECT id,valueof(col_name) val FROM table1
```

which returns

```
|id|val|
| 1|142|
| 2|136|
| 3|103|
```

Comment: Please show your sample input output for better understanding

Comment: What about your input?

Comment: I have a table and a form of query. What do I need to add?

Comment: Normalise your schema

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP (or modify the logic accordingly), you can do something like-

```
$colNames = array(col1, col5, col100); // or SELECT col_name FROM 
                                          table_name and store it in $colNames
foreach ($colNames as $val) {
  $query = "SELECT $val FROM table_name WHERE col_name={$val}";
  //execute this and store its result one-by-one into another array.
}
```

as I'm not sure if it could be done with single query.

Comment: I need this kind of data to display in a single Delphi dataset and DBGrid. I need single pure MySQL Query.